# what is the difference between perspective origin and transform origin in css

Tags: css

As i understand it is probably how it looks is perspective, and how it actually moves around in its space is origin.

I am more clear on transform origin and not so much on perspective origin.

Could someone give me links or explanation what perspective it and how origin matters.

Comment: [perspective-origin](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/properties/perspective-origin) vs [transform origin](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/properties/transform-origin)

Comment: could you provide a picture demonstration for perspective origin

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**perspective** is used to set the view angle for a element's children.
**perspective origin** is the point in space from where you are looking at the element

**transform** is the simple coordinate thing which is used to rotate/translate object(element).
**transform origin** sets the point about which you are translating/rotating an object.

**for an instance** you want to rotate an div at 45 degrees about x-axis(horizontal axis).
you use `transform:rotateX(45deg);`
[image]

div will rotate but you still see a rectangle on screen as you are looking at it from z axis with no perspective.

**but when you increase perspective**, you will see the 3d view of the div.
[image]
 the center of your eye is set by `perspective-origin`.
default value is `50% 50%` means center.
increasing and decreasing x or y value will move your "eye" accordingly.
[image]

transform origin on the other hand sets the point of transform for example if you need to rotate an rectangle about any other point other than its center, the you will use `transform-origin` property
[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

**[perspective-origin Property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/perspective-origin)**:- Set a 3D element's base placement. The perspective-origin CSS property determines the position the viewer is looking at. It is used as the vanishing point by the perspective property.

**[transform-origin Property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)**:- Set a rotated element's base placement